# Laravel 5.2 validation errors not appearing

Tags: php, validation, laravel, laravel-5

I am trying to get validation errors to show up in Laravel.

I have a UserController set up like so:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\User;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
//Use Request;
Use Flash;
Use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class UserController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Show the profile for the given user.
     *
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return Response
     */
    public function showProfile($id)
    {
        return view('user.profile', ['user' => User::findOrFail($id)]);
    }

    public function store(Request $request) {
        $this->validate($request, [
            'email' => 'required|unique:users|email|max:255',
        ]);

        if($this) {

        $input = Request::all();

        User::create($input);

        return redirect('/');

        }
        else {

            return redirect('/')->withErrors($validator);
        }
    }
}
```

In my view (layout.blade.php), I have included:

```
@if (count($errors) > 0)
@foreach ($errors->all() as $error)
   {{!! $errors !!}}
@endforeach
@endif
```

To account for the route, I have:

```
Route::group(['middleware' => ['web']], function () {
    Route::get('/', function (){
        return view('home');
    });
});
```

Unfortunately, when I enter "bad" data that shouldn't be verified, I am not seeing any error (but it is not being stored in the db, so there's that).

One other note, when the blade template is rendered, I am seeing an extra "}" bracket, which I'm not sure why that is there.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are a couple things wrong or that can be improved here. The store method on the UserController has a lot of weird issues. `$this` will always be true because objects are true in php. Also, you pass in `$validator` into `withErrors` which doesn't make sense because there's no variable `validator`.

```
public function store(Request $request) {
    $this->validate($request, [
        'email' => 'required|unique:users|email|max:255',
    ]);

    User::create(Request::all());
    return redirect('/');
}
```

The `validate` method will throw an `Illuminate\Foundation\Validation\ValidationException` if there is a validation error. This exception should be listed in the `$dontReport` instance variable in `App\Exceptions\Handler` as seen below:

```
protected $dontReport = [
    AuthorizationException::class,
    HttpException::class,
    ModelNotFoundException::class,
    ValidationException::class,
];
```

If you have changed these values, removed, or modified the `ValidatesRequest` trait you may have broken this functionality.

Your error reporting code is not correct either:

```
@foreach ($errors->all() as $error)
   {!! $errors->first() !!}
@endforeach
```

There are 3 changes here. First I removed the outer errors size check, this doesn't really get you anything. Next, I fixed your extra `}` error, the syntax for un-escaping data is `{!! $errors->first() !!}`. Lastly, I called `->first()` this returns the first error associated with that particular field.

I think it's important to note that the validation exception will create a redirect response to the previous page. The logic for determining the previous page can be found in `Illuminate\Routing\UrlGenerator::previous()`.

Answer (score 17):

In laravel version 5.2.41, the middleware web is thrown out.

Means adding the routes inside `Route::group(['middleware' => ['web']], function () {` will make the validation not work.

Comment: OMG! I spent almost an hour trying to figure this out until I wrote your message. It is completely true!
I am following a tutorial that is a few months old and they still use the 'middleware web' which I found funny because when I created my Laravel project, such thing wasn't on the route.php file.
I just removed it and put it back the way it was and I am able to read my errors now. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The errors block should be:

```
@if (count($errors) > 0)
    <div class="alert alert-danger">
        <ul>
        @foreach ($errors->all() as $error)
            <li>{{ $error }}</li>
        @endforeach
        </ul>
    </div>
@endif
```

Assuming you're using Bootstrap for the alerts.

You also don't have `$validator` defined. You need to do something like this:

```
$validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [
    'email' => 'required|unique:users|email|max:255',
]);
```

Instead of `$this->validate()`.

That should do it.

Comment: controllers have a validate method that throws an exception, you dont have to change to making a validator yourself.

Answer (score 0):

If it is still not working and you have tried several things like

1. Moving `ShareErrorsFromSession::class` from `$middlewareGroups` to `$middleware`

2. Removing the `web.php` to `web` middleware

Try modifying the request headers to

```
Accept: application/json
```

Or you can also create a new middleware that will modify the request header like this:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class ModifyAcceptHeaderMiddleware
{
    public function handle(Request $request, Closure $next)
    {
        $request->headers->set('Accept', 'application/json');

        return $next($request);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to remove "\Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession::class" from 'middleware' in Kernel.php, it must be only in the 'web' group.

Answer (score -1):

```
@if(count(($errors->all()) > 0))
@foreach($errors->all() as $error)
    <div class="alert alert-danger">
        {{$error}}
    </div>
@endforeach
@endif
```